# Using cdn (aws cloudfront) inside Google kubernetes engine

Tags: architecture, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-cloudfront, system-design, ingress-nginx

I have an application running on gke. It has pods of backend and frontend servers, at least initially 1 replica each. For clientside ui, it has a ui-deployment and ui-cluster-service. I have this app at an IP 35.244.xx.xx. I have this at abcxyz.com. I used ingress for routing, so that every route at '/' will be handled by frontend deployment, which can make reqs to '/server/xxx' this by ingress is sent to backend deployment. I want to use a cdn for frontend instead of a deployment in kubernetes. I have frontend of app deployed on aws cloudfront.

Is it just possible to config in ingress so that any search to abcxyz.com/(or)35.244.xx.xx/ will have served content of xxx.x.cdn.cloudfront.net? Rather than using cdn as face of app which communicates with gke.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing specific from a GKE-perspective, but I think what you want to do is use a [custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#CreatingCNAME) with CloudFront.

So rather than point `abcxyz.com` at the GKE LB IP, you'd be creating a CNAME record in CloudFront which points `abcxyz.com -> xxx.x.cdn.cloudfront.net`.  You'd also then create a different FQDN for the GKE LB IP and then use that as the origin in your CloudFront distribution:

```
...
Origins:
  - CustomOriginConfig:
      HTTPPort: 80
      OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
    DomainName: "lb.abcxyz.com"
...
```

Alternatively, if you don't have to use CloudFront, you can use [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#cloud_cdn) directly with GKE Ingress.